# MySQL - TEXT vs CHAR and VARCHAR

Tags: mysql, text, types, char, varchar

Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083680/questions-about-types-in-mysql), a doubt popped into my head:

- char and varchar can store up to 255 chars
- text can store up to 65k chars
- char size in bytes is number of chars
- varchar size in bytes is number of chars **used** + 1

So how much bytes does TEXT actually occupy? ~65KB or number of chars **used** + 1?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[mysql]+text+vs+varchar

Comment: `varchar size in bytes is number of chars used + 1` This actually depends on the encoding used in the table. It could, for example, be `((# of chars) * 2) + 1` for 2-byte characters. Remember it's number of *characters* not number of *bytes*.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

TEXT is a variable length datatype, with a maximum of 65,000 characters.

LONGTEXT can be used for over 4 trillion characters.

To answer your question: it's a variable lenght, and it will only occupy the amount of characters you store.

Comment: Plus a little bit of overhead to indicate that length - and LONGTEXT has more overhead than TEXT has more overhead than VARCHAR.

Comment: True: "LONG" in "LONGTEXT" actually indicates how much characters. A long value is 8 bytes, so the overhead is 8 bytes. Though it's insignificant, thus I didn't mention it.

Comment: Logically, TEXT is also stored as a BLOB

Answer (score 9):

TEXT occupies a number actual length of your data + 2 bytes.

Comment: Soooo if you're storing 256 or more characters, VARCHAR and TEXT take up the same amount of storage space?